# Jquery autocomplete not working. not able to give value to data response(jQuery.map(data.Data)

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, jquery-ui

I am trying to learn jQuery on MVC. everything seems fine but autocomplete is not working. I debbuged it and may my success method is not working. Please help me .

My controller code:-

```
public ActionResult GetName(string term)
        {

            AjaxResponse objAjaxResponse = new AjaxResponse();

            List<AutoCompleteModel> objData = masterRepository.getAutoComplete(term);

            objAjaxResponse.Status = AjaxResponseStatusCodes.Ok;
            objAjaxResponse.Message = "Autocom";
            objAjaxResponse.Data = objData;
            return Json(objAjaxResponse);
        }
```

Repository code:-

```
public List<AutoCompleteModel> getAutoComplete(string MyName)
        {
            List<AutoCompleteModel> adasd = new List<AutoCompleteModel>();
            //adasd = this.DB.ExecuteSprocAccessor<AutoCompleteModel>("dbo.[getNameByName]",MyName).ToList();

            using (IDataReader IReader = this.DB.ExecuteReader("dbo.getNameByName", MyName))
            {
                MapListRecord<AutoCompleteModel>(IReader, adasd);
                //MapRecord(IReader, adasd);
                IReader.NextResult();
            }

            return adasd;
        }
```

Jquery:-

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
jQuery("#MyName").keyup(function () {
        BindAutoCompleteGrid();
    });

});

function BindAutoCompleteGrid() {
    jQuery("#MyName").autocomplete({
        //minLength: options.minLength == undefined ? 1 : options.minLength,
        source: function (request, response) {
            jQuery.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: GetNameUrl,
                data: { term : request.term },                
                //data: options.data == undefined ? { "term": jQuery(options.textObject).val() } : options.data,
                dataType: "json",
                cache: false,
                global: false,
                responseType: "json",
                sucesscallbackfunction: 'onSucessGetName'

            });
            }
            });
}

function onSucessGetName(data, response) {
    response(jQuery.map(data.Data, function (item) {
        return {
            label: item["Value"],
            name: item["Name"]
        }
    }));
}
```

textbox:-

```
<div>
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.MyName, new { @id="MyName",@name="MyName", @class="txtCustDetails"})
</div>
```

Any help or suggestion is welcome. Thankyou..

Comment: Can you explain it more..what's not working ? and did you checked console log?

Comment: was not getting into success method but it is going now but still not working.

Comment: I'm sure you got some error, did you checked in console?

Comment: Yes, i just inspect your code and found this : `label: item["Value"]` this should be `label: item.Value` and the same for `name`

Comment: @Div . No bro I checked in console. If there would have been errors I could Have at least tried. Okay let me try the code.

Comment: I am getting an empty drop down in UI no Names in it.

Comment: Alert you `item` and check, get anything into it or not?

Comment: Yes getting the items. but my dropdown is empty. what can I do to get it?

Comment: Provide working fiddler. or else compare your code with [this](http://imgr.es/3D0O) code

Comment: Thanks Bro. Changed Item.Value to item.MyName and it worked. I was silly while debugging. thanks for help.

Comment: Glad to know that :)

Comment: to be precise matched it with my Public string MyName{get; set;} in model class.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see `sucesscallbackfunction` in the list of available settings for `jQuery.ajax()`: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/. Also, even if the callback is being executed, the `response` callback would not be in scope.

Try this:

```
function BindAutoCompleteGrid() {
  jQuery("#MyName").autocomplete({
    source: function(request, response) {
      jQuery.ajax({
        //...
        //sucesscallbackfunction: 'onSucessGetName' // remove
      }).done(function(data) {
        response(jQuery.map(data.Data, function(item) {
          return {
            label: item["Value"],
            name: item["Name"]
          }
        }));
      });
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Okay I tried it now I am getting Value in data. when I type 's' 4 names are are picked up from database but I am still not getting the List shown on UI . Please Guide me More.

Comment: Thanks for help bro.

Answer (score 0):

Edited jQuery

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
jQuery("#MyName").autocomplete({
  source: function (request, response) {
            jQuery.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: GetNameUrl,
                data: { term: request.term}, 
                dataType: "json",
                cache: false,
                global: false,
                responseType: "json",
                success : (function (data) {

                    response(jQuery.map(data.Data, function (item) {
                        return {
                            label: item.MyName
                           // name: item["MyName"]
                        }
                       // jQuery("#MyName").val(item["value"])
                    }))

                })
            })
        }
     })
});
```

Comment: I think you not need to add this to as an answer, this is different from your first question.